# What is the meaning of “in that parents’ basement sort of way”?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of *parents’ basement*?

> In that parents’ basement sort of way
>
> He’s kind of cute, in that parents’ basement sort of way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This refers to the stereotype of men who live with their parents (often in the basement) for an abnormally long time after graduating high school and/or college.

The stereotype depicts men who are "nerds" and are socially inept. For some women, this can be an endearing quality.